# TypeError when rendering page

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I don't understand why it keeps saying that the int object is not iterable. any help guys??

I'm trying to:

1. get the list of users that are following us
2. initialize an empty posts list and set qs equal to none
3. loop through the users list
   3A) for each user that we are following - grab it's profile
   3B) for every profile that we know have - grab the posts
   3C) add the posts to the post list
4. grab our posts
5. if posts list isn't empty sort the posts by created date

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\social\project4\network\templates\network\profile_test.html, error at line 12
'int' object is not iterable
2   
3   {% block title %}
4       Profiles
5   {% endblock title %}
6   
7   {% block body %}
8       <p><b>My Posts: </b> {{profile.get_my_posts}}</p>
9       <p><b>My Posts number: </b> {{profile.get_num_posts}}</p>
10      <p><b>Following Profiles: </b> {{profile.get_following}}</p>
11      <p><b>Following Profiles List: </b> {{profile.get_following_users}}</p>
12      <p><b>My Posts and Posts of Following Users: </b> {{profile.get_all_posts}}</p>
13  {% endblock %}
14
```

```
def get_all_posts(self):
        users = [user for user in self.get_following()]
        posts = [0]
        qs = None
        for u in users:
            p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
            p_posts = p.post_set.all()
            posts.append(p_posts)
        my_posts = self.post_set.all()
        posts.append(my_posts)
        if len(posts) > 0:
            qs = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj: obj.created)
        return qs
```

Comment: You say "initialize an empty `posts` list" but it's not empty, it contains the number 0 - is that intentional? An empty `posts` list would be written `[]`.

Comment: Thank you! No, it wasn't on purpose.. I didn't see that lol @wander-nauta